# str_replace array from controller laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I want to replace `$reqcolaborate` to `$namepar`, I have this controller:

```
$reqcolaborate        =   DB::table("pra_kpis")
                          ->distinct()
                          ->pluck("kpi_parameters_id");
$namepar              = DB::table('kpi_parameters')->pluck('name');
$idpar                = DB::table('kpi_parameters')->pluck('id');

@foreach ($reqcolaborate as $parreq)                         
         <option value="{{$parreq}}">
         {{$parreq = str_replace($idpar, $namepar, $parreq)}}
         </option>
@endforeach
```

for example data

```
$namepar = array ('MFS active user', '#4g active users','VOLTE');
$idpar   = array (1,2,12);
$reqcolaborate = array (1,2,12);
```

but, why the result in dropdown like this

```
<option>MFS active user</option>
<option>#4g active users</option>
<option>MFS active user#4g active users</option>
```

i want the result in dropdown like this

```
<option>MFS active user</option>
<option>#4g active users</option>
<option>VOLTE</option>
```

Comment: (I don't use Laravel) what happens when you remove `$parreq = ` in your `foreach()`?  You don't need the variable declaration right?

Comment: You could define a relationship to access it. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships. 
str_replace is replacing "12" with "1" & "2"

Comment: i am not getting your question can you tell what is your expected output

Comment: the result in dropdown

Comment: what should be the value of option and text of option can you post?

Comment: the result in dropdown #3 <option>VOLTE</option> not <option> MFS active user #4g active users</option>

Comment: still not clear where is the value?

Comment: @YandraAdie can you update your quuestion with excpected output with each option value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by Matts under the question, `str_replace()` will be mangling your intended replacements by targetting substrings instead of fullstrings.  When you want to replace whole strings without using regular expressions with anchors, you can write your own associative "lookup" array using `$idpar` and `$namepar`.

Here's [a demonstration](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5d8208a1fa194ecb70be1d88a2f1c45c759ac557):

```
$namepar = array ('MFS active user', '#4g active users','VOLTE');
$idpar   = array (1,2,12);
$reqcolaborate = array (1,2,12);
$assocpar=array_combine($idpar,$namepar);  // write an associative array to relate $idpar with $namepar

foreach ($reqcolaborate as $parreq){
     echo $assocpar[$parreq],"\n";
}
```

Output:

```
MFS active user
#4g active users
VOLTE
```

---

In your controller (again, I don't use Laravel), you can write something like this:

```
$reqcolaborate = DB::table("pra_kpis")
                     ->distinct()
                     ->pluck("kpi_parameters_id");
$lookup        = array_combine(
                     DB::table('kpi_parameters')->pluck('id'),
                     DB::table('kpi_parameters')->pluck('name')
                 );

@foreach ($reqcolaborate as $parreq)                         
    <option value="{{$parreq}}">
        {{ $lookup[$parreq] }}
    </option>
@endforeach
```

Or if there is a chance that an `id` won't exist in the lookup array, perhaps:

```
@foreach ($reqcolaborate as $parreq)                         
    <option value="{{$parreq}}">
        {{ isset($lookup[$parreq]) ? $lookup[$parreq] : 'Whoops, replacement not found in lookup array -- do something!' }}
    </option>
@endforeach
```